# How to test injected mock with try-catch

Tags: java, spring, mockito, try-catch, inject

I'm doing simple unit test by using mockMvc with springboot. SampleCtrl.java is origin source code and SampleCtrlTest.java is test source code. There are 3 mocks injected to SampleCtrl and they are working well except SampleService class. As you can see, SampleService wrapped with try-catch block. So, I have no idea how to call the method in mock class to get return or throw exception in test source code.

I removed try-catch block in origin code, also given() method in test code. It worked well. That's why I think the try-catch block is undoubted reason to make error.

**SampleCtrl.java**

```
@PostMapping(path = "/save", consumes = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> setEmp(@RequestBody 
List<EmpSaveVo> vos) {

    result.clear();
    try {
        msg = service.setEmp(vos);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        msg = e.getMessage();
    }
    result = messageTrans.getMapLang(msg);

    return messageReturn.getRestResp(result, msg);
}
```

**SampleCtrlTest.java**

```
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Mock
private SampleService service;

@Mock
private MessageTrans messageTrans;

@Mock
private MessageReturn messageReturn;

@InjectMocks
private SampleCtrl sampleCtrl;

@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(sampleCtrl).build();
}

@Test
public void givenEmployeeDataWhenPostEmpSave() throws Exception {
    List<EmpSaveVo> empSaveVos = new ArrayList<>();
    EmpSaveVo empSaveVo = new EmpSaveVo();
    empSaveVo.setEmployeeId(100L);
    empSaveVo.set_status((long) Status.Modified.getStatus());
    empSaveVos.add(empSaveVo);

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String element = gson.toJson(empSaveVos);

    String msg = "Test";

    Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    result.put("message", msg); 

    given(service.setEmp(empSaveVos)).willThrow(new Exception());
    given(messageTrans.getMapLang(msg)).willReturn(result);
    given(messageReturn.getRestResp(any(), anyString()))
    .willReturn(new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(result, HttpStatus.OK));

    mockMvc.perform(post("/api/emp/save")
            .content(element)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

Consequently, I want to see this console log.

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
              Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8"]
     Content type = application/json;charset=UTF-8
              Body = {"message":"Test"}
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

Comment: Why are you doing `mockMvc.perform(post("/api/emp/save")` instead you can just call `sampleCtrl.setEmp(List<EmpSaveVo> vos)` in the test and assert the output you are expecting.

Comment: Your mock will never match. This `given(service.setEmp(empSaveVos)).` will never be called, from the pov of the mock as it is a different instance of the list/entity you are persisting. Hence it won't match and it will result in the default behavior of returning `null` instead of throwing an exception. Make your matching smarter so that it will return an error.

Comment: Ubercool / Because of persistence layer. DB is connected with JNDI and I don't want to make another SpringBoot Test Application.

Comment: M. Deinum / The other mock class such as MessageTrans, and MessageReturn can be injected and called successfully. However, as you told me, It's better to find the other smarter way. Anyway, thank you for your advice